# Convert system date to ISO format using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to convert system date to ISO format in below fashion using momentjs

```
2015-02-17T19:05:00.000Z
```

I'm however unable to find the parameter that I need to use to get it in the format which I want. I tried below piece of code..

```
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z");
```

I get output as 2015-02-02 17:24+05:30.

How can I get it as 2015-02-02T17:24:00.000Z

Comment: You don't need moment.js at all, use the built–in [*Date.prototype.toISOString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.43). There's a [*polyfill on MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) for old browsers like IE 8.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is pretty well covered in the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/). But, they're long, so here's the specifics:

For some reason, momentjs's definition of ISO 8601 differs from the [ECMAScript](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) one, so it isn't built in. The format is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ` and it must be in UTC (the `Z` denotes this).

So, [`moment().utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/) makes sure the timezone is correct.

Then [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) it:

```js
moment().utc().format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]");
// 2015-02-02T21:38:04.092Z
```

The `Z` is [escaped with square brackets](http://momentjs.com/docs/#escaping-characters). We can do this safely because we forced UTC.

The rest of the characters denote various time elements according to the [format table](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

---

You could also do what RobG said and use the native date object. In case you are starting with a moment:

```
moment().toDate().toISOString( )
// 2015-02-02T21:40:06.395Z
```

Comment: Sweet mother of lord, finally I got the format for ISO for moment `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]` :\

Comment: Thanks : works for moment-timezone because toISOString() not

Comment: @slicedtoad stuck with a similar issue, using your approach, works in converting the date to an ISO format but doesnt return the correct date - an example if the date that i am trying to convert is 05-04-2019 format dd-mm-yyyy it converts it to 2019-04-07T22:29:06.754Z which is not a correct date, what could be the issue here? this is the way i use it ----const stringinv = retreive.data.v_invoice_date, --let mmtinv = moment().utc(invoice).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]")